# Draggable, stackable, text with transparent background in c#

Tags: c#, text, graphics, game-engine, transparent

Is there a way to have a draggable, stackable, true transparency text? I have a game done in c# that allows me to drag text from the right of my form and drop it on the left and when the child has built a sentence, he can play it to hear the sentence he made. I would like for there not to be any box around the text as I drag it, just the floating word itself.

Is there a way? Right now I was just starting to look into using a game engine to get that effect and thought to ask here first.

Thanks

Comment: winforms? wpf? other?

Comment: you can easily do this in WPF. winforms' support for transparency is really limited.

Comment: I can't easily find how to make a movable text object without the box showing in WPF. The tutorials I've found are showing me how to do things that I could have done in a regular windows form application. Can you point me in the right direction?